# Client PC not downloading WSUS updates on Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, windows-server-2012

I have a client pc on windows 10 that can ping the WSUS box and vice versa but the updates are just not coming down despite the windows firewall being off and the antivirus being off.
This is a unique environment where the network is air gapped and there is no access to the internet so normal rules do not apply. I can see in the Reporting Events notepad file the log shows that 9 windows updates are detected but they just will not download.

However I can ping the wsus server machine from the client and vice versa yet the software distribution folder is not being populated and it only has 99mb. Whenever I reboot a new folder in SLS appears but we still cant get our updates down. I suspect it maybe a folder permission issue but I cant remember how we fixed it last time. Any suggestions gratefully accepted

29th June:

I tried everything down to Rebuild the Automatic Update Agent Store and nothing worked even giving everyone full control to the wsus content folder didnt work. One of the log files in the Software distribution folder reports that there are 9 updates detected but it just doesnt download them. I can ping the client from wsus and vice versa but I guess this means ICMP is not blocked.

Any further suggestions gratefully accepted. An ex colleague has suggested that Server 2012 is too to deploy wsus updates to Windows 10 21H2 LTSC. Does anyone have any thoughts on that please? Cheers in advance :-)

30th June:
We approved windows updates that were not authorised and tried to install 2012 report viewer but that needs a small sql server 2019 pack and after installing that we still got an error saying that 2012 report viewer is required. We suspect permissions. A registry hack off youtube also failed to fix this. Im now on holiday for a week so i hope its fixed on my return lol

Comment: Please try this [troubleshooting advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/configmgr/update-management/troubleshoot-issues-with-wsus-client-agents) and report on the results. [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1792290/edit) your post rather than answering in comments.

Comment: why did you want me to edit my post instead of reply? I didnt understand?

Comment: It's better if all the information is concentrated in one place - your post.